# Let G be an abelian group, and V be a faithful irreducible representation of G over C

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

This seems kind of obvious to me but I'm really having trouble thinking of what to do! Any help would be appreciated.

Let G be a finite abelian group, and V be a faithful irreducible representation
of G over C. Show each element g ∈ G fixes at least one subspace of V dimension 1

Comment: What does faithful have to do with it?

Comment: It's for a later part that I have already proved. I just need help with this first bit :)

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? If you take $G = \{ \pm 1 \}$ and $V=\Bbb{C}$ be the unique faithful irreducible representation of $G$, then $-1$ does not fix anything.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian any irreducible representation is of dimension $1$, so depending on what you mean by fixing a subspace it can be either trivial or false...

Comment: perhaps jackwo meant "preserves". but any such representation would be 1-dimensional anyway

Comment: I think I just need to show that for every element of the group it is possible to produce a 1-dimensional subspace of V?

Comment: The representation maps $g$ onto a matrix $\rho(g)$. Because ${\mathbb C}$ is algebraically closed, $\rho(g)$ must have an eigenvalue with associated eigenvector $v \in V$. Then the subspace spanned by $v$ is fixed by $g$. By the way, your terminology is wrong. A representation is not a vector space, it is a group homomorphism $\rho:G \to {\rm GL}(V)$ to the group of linear maps from $V \to V$, so you can think of $\rho(g)$ as an $n \times n$ matrix, where $n=\dim V$.